# Git alias changed on its own

Tags: macos, git, zsh

I'm using macOS and zsh.

Yesterday, when I typed `gl`, it was a shortcut for `git pull`.

Now, all of a sudden, `gl` seems to refer to `git log --graph --decorate ...`

Why is that? How can I make `gl` an alias for `git pull` again?

Comment: How did you make it an alias for `git pull`? The same probably works now. As for how it changed ... that's something you'd have to investigate. For instance you might have installed a patch or software that changed it.

Comment: You're using oh-my-zsh, I guess? The git plugin last changed [5 months ago](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git).

Comment: The problem was that the git plugin from zsh didn't load. Fixed it with this command `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh`. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227521/1769177

According to this answer, the oh-my-zsh plugin containing the git aliases wasn't being sourced.